# NIntegrate (multi-dimensional integral)

Tags: numerical-integration

I am interested in the numerical evaluation of the following integral:

$\int \prod_{i=1}^n dx_i \delta(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i) \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$

where $f(x)$ is a complicated function. Unfortunately NIntegrate seems to give an answer with too large errors; this seems to be problem of the multi-dimensional integral.
The function contains the phase fluctuations ($\sim e^{ikx}$), which could be one of the reasons.
In practice $n\sim 5$, although it is certainly better if I could take $n$ large.

For comparison, I can also consider an integral

$\int \prod_{i=1}^n dx_i \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$

but instead of evaluation this whole expression in NIntegrate, I could factorize the integral to be

$\prod_{i=1}^n \left(\int dx_i\, f_i(x_i)\right)$, evaluate the 1-dimensional integral first and then take a product. This seems to give an answer which is numerically much better than NIntegrating the n-dimensional integral. [I am numerically checking the known mathematical identity so I have something to compare with. The one with the delta function corresponds to $SU(N)$, the one without to $U(N)$.]

The trouble with the one above, with 1 delta function, is that the integral does not factorize. However I hope there is a way to achieve numerical accuracy, rather than brute-force NIntegrate of the whole expression.

In any case I would appreciate any suggestions for better numerical accuracy.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you included some (minimal) working example.

Comment: You are integrating over the hyperplane defined by delta. There is no way you will get good results with `NIntegrate` because the results depend on the (essentially zero) probability of the grid scheme exactly hitting the hyperplane. (and if it does you'll get an error that delta is not numerical) I think you need to roll your own quadrature scheme which will require gridding out the hyperplane.  Not a trivial task even for n=3.

Comment: pondering this some more, a good approach may be a monte carlo integration, where you generate random sets `x_i` s.t `Sum[x_i]==0` and all x_i within integration region. I'm Pretty sure there was a question on that topic recently.